# LinearLayout add a view above the other views Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to add a view to the top of my linear layout. The following code is adding my view to the end of the application layout.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
layout.addView(adView);
```

How do I update this code so that my adView is at the top of my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can specify at what index you want to `addView` at.

```
layout.addView(child, index);
```

Comment: Interesting, don't know about such method.

Comment: So index would be `0` in this case, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these approaches:
1) add an empty `LinearLayout` to place where you want to show Ad and then add `adView` to them.
2) add `adView` in you xml-layout(if it possible) and hide/show them when you need by using `setVisible()` method.

Also you can use `RelativeLayout` instead `LinearLayout` but it harder to add View to them dynamically.